Pac4j - With multiple realms: Pac4jPrincipal cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
I´m getting the following error if I have more than 1 realm:
class io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jPrincipal cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jPrincipal is in unnamed module of loader

Issue is here:


Shiro.ini
securityManager.realms = $pac4jRealm, $jdbcRealm, $tcRealm

    

Here my pom.xml
<pac4jVersion>5.7.7</pac4jVersion>
<bujiVersion>8.1.0</bujiVersion>
<jeePac4jVersion>7.1.0</jeePac4jVersion>

    

How can this be solved?
Is this a bug in the Pa4j library - why is it not converted to String?
Let me know if you need more information.

This might be a bug in the buji-pac4j library. Can you copy/paste the full stack trace of the exception?

I´ve created my custom "ShiroJdbcRealmCustom" and added a check:  if (result instanceof String) {username = (String) username;
I haven´t the full stack trace, but it´s this issue: cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jPrincipal is in unnamed module of loader

OK. I see the problem. buji-pac4j only stores a Pac4jPrincipal class while regular realms except a String. It now stores both. Can you try with 8.1.1-SNAPSHOT?

is this already in Maven available?

I just cut the v8.1.1 and v9.0.2 releases. They will show up in the Maven central repository within a few minutes/hours.

Great, thanks - the requirements are still the same? Java version etc. ?
